# Creating subdomain in c# on DiscountAsp host(godaddt)

Tags: subdomain, discountasp

i have a website and i want to create an interface where a user can create his website on my host.it should be a sub domain for my domain.
my Host is DiscountAsp.Net OR Godadday.i just read and they provide add-on with the name Unlimited Subdomain for this.They have  code how to redirect here is the link
http://support.discountasp.net/KB/a369/how-to-redirect-a-subdomain-to-a-subdirectory.aspx?KBSearchID=389848

Now is it possible in C#?how programitically i will create subdomains having a sample template in asp.net for all users?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in you CS file, in the Page_Load method

```
if (Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] == "test.yourdomain.com")
    Server.Transfer(@"~/Test/Default.html");
```

Do not forget to add the Test folder and mark it as an application from Web Application Tool